# API in EC2 instance using port 5000 successfully but when reaching from load balancer the port isn't working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance in an Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS.
I uploaded my Flask API in my server and keep up the service with **tmux** (in case you need it, I did it like this: https://www.twilio.com/blog/deploy-flask-python-app-aws but instead of port 8080 it was port 5000).

Since putting my API in the server I have testing it, every endpoint works normally.

My next step was to create with Route 53 and Certificate Manger a domain, a SSL Certificate for that domain, and add the CNAME record:
[image]
[image]

The first thing I did to know I could successfully reach my API from my domain was to create a Simple A record with the ip of that domain (btw, I set an Elastic IP for that EC2 instance).

So far so good, I'm able to use `http://mydomain:5000` to successfully reach my API. No issues there, the endpoints are still working as they should.

Then what I had problems with (I didn't know as I'm pretty new in this add SSL certificates with Certificate Manager) is that even if the certificate was issued, it wasn't really put "In Use". I discovered it isn't that easy and the next thing I need to do was for the certificate to be linked to my EC2 instance, the CNAME record wasn't enough.

I searched how to do that, I had some setbacks and kinda discouraged as many guides were about using S3 or didn't mention an EC2 instance, but I found one and followed it, here it is: https://youtu.be/bWPTq8z1vFY?t=533 (the part about Load Balancers is less than 3 mins).

I created my Load Balancer following that tutorial. An Application Load Balancer (HTTP/HTTPS), Internet-facing, the Availability Zones include the one where my EC2 instance is, my SSL certificate is selected (and it's really the only one I have), the Load Balancer is in the same Security Group as my EC2 instance (I even Ctrl Fed to check it's the same string), and I have 2 listeners: HTTP and HTTPS:
[image]

The next part was to change my Simple A Record with just the ip address (as that was just HTTP but HTTPS wasn't working) to a Simple A Record for the Load Balancer. I deleted the one I created first

Even if the screens are a little different (although it is from 2020, AWS just updated the UI), here's what I'm doing when adding the new A Record:
[image]

And here's the end result:
[image]

After waiting a couple of minutes for the update to be ready I try to reach my endpoints with `https://mydomain:5000` but the requests fail.

Here's the difference from before, when I tried to reach `my_ip_address:5000` or `http:mydomain:5000` this message appeared, which makes sense as I don't have anything to return when just reaching the API (that's totally normal behavior):
[image]

But now it says I'm unable to reach the site:
[image]

I'm even getting a 502 error if I just enter `https:mydomain` (which I wasn't even getting before):
[image]

Also, here's how my target group is having health issues, which I don't get why (I'm still learning, probably something to do with the config):
[image]

Which, again, probably something to do with the configuration which I still don't get, because my EC2 instance is healthy:
[image]

I don't know how to procede from here, I have been searching for clues and other alternatives but the alternatives are even older and outdated.

If you have any alternatives of how I should do this process or if there's something wrong with the way I'm doing this, please, guide me, I'm kinda stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Clearly your HCs are failing. Does you app/api work on the instance when your curl it directly, without using ALB? Or if you ssh into the instance, can you curl it from the inside?

Comment: Yeah, if it's without the ALB, there's no issue. I tested it both with Postman and my web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a thing after all with the configuration.

As my target is a specific port for my API, I needed to do that instead of the normal port `80` for HTTP.

Here's what needs to be done, instead of setting HTTP port 80 as in the next image:
[image]

It should be `Port: 5000` in my case. At first I thought it was correct to leave it as 80 but I'm not really using port 80 for my API.

It's actually pretty simple but for all of those that are starting with AWS and all this configurations are as new to you as they are for me, be careful.

Next step for the DNS records is to leave the A Record as `Alias to Application and Classic Load Balancer` and to access the endpoints you no longer need to put it as `https://mydomain:5000`, just `https://mydomain` is enough as the Application Load Balancer is already taking care of that.